# yaml parse error helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

im getting

> Error: YAML parse error on myApp-infra/templates/my.yaml: error
>   converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 20: found unexpected ':'

below is  helm install --dry-run --debug ./myApp output

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: spark-slave-service
  labels:
    app: spark-slave
spec:
  selector:
    app: spark-slave
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: spark-slave-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: spark-slave
  serviceName: "spark-slave-service"
  replicas: 3 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template: # create pods using pod definition in this template
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spark-slave
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: spark-slave-container
        image: <image url>
        command: [<mycommand>
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/tmp/data"
          name: slave-pvc
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      labels:
        app: spark-slave
      name: slave-pvc
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
      storageClassName: "rook-block"
```

Comment: Is it a typo in your question here - `command: [<mycommand>`?

Comment: I believe you&#39;ll have to split the yaml for each Service and StatefulSet before converting to json. Or create **kind: List** for each items. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/hack/testdata/list.yaml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When helm encounters parse errors while processing multiple YAML documents in a single file (like your case) the error message can be a bit misleading. Although it says `line 20`, that point is in reference to the beginning of one of the YAML documents in the file, not the beginning of the file itself. With most parse errors, you should check the line it mentions as well as the previous line for issues. In your case, it looks like Line 19 of the StatefulSet document on the `command` line would cause it.